# Get-Acl does not refresh the acl correctly when an identity reference is renamed

Tags: powershell, acl

I have a directory with a simple ACL:

The `Get-Acl . | Format-List` command outputs the following

```
Path   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::mypath
Owner  : BUILTIN\Administrateurs
Group  : AD\Utilisateurs du domaine
Access : AD\GL_test_RW Allow  Modify, Synchronize
         AD\GL_test_RO Allow  ReadAndExecute, Synchronize
```

If I rename the groups GL_test* with the rename-adobject command, and I if re-run Get-Acl, the group names are not updated !

The SID of the groups, however, are correctly translated if I do something like:

```
$acl.access[0].IdentityReference.Translate([Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]).Value
```

But if I translate it back to a name, the old group names are returned !

How can I force Get-Acl to return the correct and new group names ?

Answer (score 0):

How long after you made that change did you re-check that ACL?  Are you sure this isn't just replication latency between DC's and it will clear up as soon as all the replicas get in sync?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem today.

`Get-Acl` is displaying the "samaccountname" of groups instead of "name".

But other cmdlet such as `"Get-AdPrincipalGroupMembership"` display the "name" of groups.

I figured that i had some groups with their "samaccountname" different than their "name".

```
Get-AdGroup -filter * | Where-Object {$_.name -ne $_.samaccountname} | format-table name, samaccountname}
```

I know this question is 2years old but think my answer can be usefull.

P-S: excuse my poor english...